# Angular 2 FormGroup Validation Types

Tags: forms, angular, validation

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.record = new FormGroup({
      movement: new FormControl(''),
      weight: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(3)]),
      date: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      comments: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(25)]),
    });
  }
```

View:

```
<div class="column col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-label">Weight</label>
              <input formControlName="weight" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Weight" />
            </div>
          </div>

<div class="column col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-label">Date</label>
              <input formControlName="date" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Date" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

I've got the above validation working just fine, but I need to change the validators on `weight` to only accept numerical values and the validators on `date` to accept a specific format `(##/##/####)`.

I've been searching forever and haven't found any built-in methods of doing this.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Add Validators.pattern("Regex expression of  your date or number")] to the other validators for weight an date. Alternatively you can also try  using the pattern attribute directly in the input tag

Answer (score 1):

There are only a small number of built-in form validation rules in Angular.

- required
- minLength
- maxLength
- pattern (which you could use for email)

**EDIT:**

More built in:

- min
- max
- email
- nullValidator
- requiredTrue

[Validators API](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) (thank you, @developer033)

If you want to do anything beyond that, you will have to code your own. They are not difficult.

You can find an example on how to build and use a custom validator at the link below.

[Custom validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validation)

If you happen to have a Pluralsight subscription, Deborah Kurata has a great course on [Angular Reactive Forms](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-reactive-forms), and there is a clip or two on custom form validation in the Validation module.

Comment: Acutally there are more built-in validators.

Comment: @developer033 I would love to see a link to that information. Do you have that handy?

Comment: Also, it's worth to mention that `min` and `max` built-in validators were rolled back in [**4.3.0-beta.0**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#430-beta0-2017-06-22) due to [**this issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17491) and won't be exported anymore (probably) in 4.3.0 **final**. Probably they should be back in v5.﻿

Comment: Is it me, or is it a little difficult to find stuff in ng docs? It's me, right? Yeah, it's me. :)

Comment: No, it happens to me sometimes also.. haha. I think the new website is a bit buggy yet. As you can see in the link, for example, there are *three* `compose()` methods :).